# c++ ABI compatibility between gcc-4.4 and gcc-4.8

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, abi

I've got a RedHat6 build platform which has **gcc-4.4.7** installed and I've built a bunch of shared and static libraries on that platform.

Now I want to build an app on the above platform which links against the above libraries along with a third party library which has been built on RedHat7 using **gcc-4.8.5**.

My app will be deployed on RedHat7 platforms.

My questions are:

Will I be able to build my app successfully on the RH6 platform?

Will my app run when deployed on the RH7 platform?

According to my understanding of [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), it seems that both versions of the toolchain have compatible ABIs, so I feel that the answer to both my questions is probably 'yes'.
A toy example I built to test it worked as expected, but I'd like to get the opinion of an experienced Linux developer.